# What is the maximum size of a vector in R

Tags: r

I am having troubles to get the result of a function as per there is a maximum size in Gb not length (although there may be equivalance) of a vector allowed in R. What do I have to do in order to find out what that is. I put the results below:

```
# Cluster Analysis
fun <- function(x) scale(BB[[x]]) # standardize variables
bb  <- lapply(I,fun)
bbb <- as.data.frame(bb)
ccc <- seq(1:length(bb))
# Determine number of clusters
# Model Based Clustering
library(mclust)
fit <- function(x) Mclust(bbb)
lapply(ccc,fit)
```

Error: no se puede ubicar un vector de tamaño  1.4 Gb

Comment: The question is as per Gb not the size of the vector in length although there maybe equivalence, unfortunatedly I can not see the vector result of the function applied.

Comment: You might try searching SO with the following query: `[r] "cannot allocate vector of size"`.